# library to generate embedding of each line of java file and embeddings must contain ast information

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree

Is there any library or API available for generating embeddings of each line of a Java code file while preserving AST (Abstract Syntax Tree) structure information? I'm already familiar with fold2vec. Are there any other alternatives?